# Uninstall the VirtualBox guest addition on CentOS 7?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I'm trying to uninstall the VirtualBox guest addition for a CentOS virtual machine.

How do I do so?

Comment: Thank you sir for correcting me, I will try to improve my writing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open a terminal and enter the following commands:

```
cd /media

cd VBOXADDITIONS_4.1.12_77218

sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall
```

This should uninstall vbox guest-additions

PS Please do some research on your own for next time because I found answer to your question through simply googling your question title [Here I found answer to your question](https://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-guest-additions)

Comment: In adittion, to direclty open the terminal in the location where GuestAdittion is installed, just right click on the folder located in media/username/ghestadittion and select 'Open in Terminal'. Then just run 'sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall'

Comment: @Gian Gomen Sure :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work if the host system is Windows 10 because VBoxLinuxAdditions is not present.

Comment: @Jonathan  Host OS doesn't really matter here, VBoxLinuxAdditions will be present in `/media` _only when_ you click on Devices > Insert Guest Additions Image

Comment: @GianGomen that's not an installation path. That's a mount point for removable media. What you describe is how to open the the `/media` path in Terminal from the file manager. This is an alternative to having to open the Terminal first and then do `cd /media`.

Comment: @Jonathan that statement is illogical. The VBoxLinuxAdditions.run is a Linux executable and will be present on the Guest Additions ISO file which you have to insert for the Linux guest system to see and read it. The host system is irrelevant, it can be Linux or Windows. And of course, VBoxLinuxAdditions.run will not run on a Windows guest system if that's what you imply, as it is a Linux executable and not a Windows executable.

Comment: @daya correct! It will be present only after inserting the ISO file on which it is contained, and as I said already, it's meant to be consumed by a Linux guest system, so the guest system is what matters, host system is irrelevant.

Comment: Replace the `/media` with `/run` if you're on Fedora 31. Also, `uninstall` is not a valid option. Where did you get that from? The linked blog post? Take note that it's "Published April 26, 2012". I did this today using Guest Additions ISO of VirtualBox 6.0.10 and when you run `sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` (with or without `uninstall` because that's not an option) you will get a long text warning you of existing Guest Additions and telling you to uninstall it using the uninstall procedure of the operating system which on Fedora is `rpm -e virtualbox-guest-additions-6.0.12-1.fc31.x86_64`.

Comment: @Jonathan this is why I know that having Windows as the host is irrelevant. I did this today with Windows 10 as host and Fedora 31 as guest system.

Answer (score 0):

f you have a version of the Guest Additions installed on your virtual machine and wish to remove it without installing new ones, you can do so by inserting the Guest Additions CD image into the virtual CD-ROM drive as described above. Then run the installer for the current Guest Additions with the uninstall parameter from the path that the CD image is mounted on in the guest, as follows:

```
sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall
```

While this will normally work without issues, you may need to do some manual cleanup of the guest in some cases, especially of the XFree86Config or xorg.conf file. In particular, if the Additions version installed or the guest operating system were very old, or if you made your own changes to the Guest Additions setup after you installed them.

You can uninstall the Additions as follows:

```
/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-version/uninstall.sh
```

Replace `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-version` with the correct Guest Additions installation directory.