# Remove VirtualBox Guest Additions from a VM that has already been migrated to Hyper V

Tags: virtualbox, hyper-v

I have moved a Centos 6 VM (used as a desktop) from Virtualbox to HyperV, and the performance is terrible. I have installed Linux Integration Services but this has hardly helped, so I would now like to try and remove Guest Additions.

The only documentation I have found [involves](https://superuser.com/questions/1343463/uninstall-the-virtualbox-guest-addition-on-centos-7) inserting the VirtualBox virtual DVD and running:

```
sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall
```

But I think it's too late for that as I'm already on HyperV.

What are my options?

Comment: Find your version of vbox [here](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/) and download the guest additions ISO file, mount it, and then run the command you listed in your post.

Comment: On a Windows install, you can just use add/remove programs to remove the guest additions. Can't you remove it the same way on linux?

Comment: @n8te that worked, thanks. Can you add that as an answer, and then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you can no longer insert the Virtualbox Guest Additions CD through the Virtualbox app, you can just download the ISO image from the official site, mount it, and then run the uninstall command from there.

1. Go to [download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.0/) and find the link to the version of Virtualbox Geust Additions you have installed (for this example, we will be using version 6.0.0).  Look for a file with a name similar to `VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.0.iso`. Download it to your virtual machine.
2. Create directory to mount your ISO by running the following:
   `sudo mkdir /mnt/iso`
3. Run the following command to mount your ISO image to the directory you just created:
   `sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop ~/Downloads/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.0.iso /mnt/iso` (or replace `~/Downloads/` with wherever you had downloaded your ISO file)
4. The contents of your ISO will now be copied into `/mnt/iso`, so change directory into that and run:
   `sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall`

Answer (score 36):

The Guest Additions package now includes an uninstaller, at least on Debian derivatives. Running the following completely removes vbox-guest-additions for me on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04:

```
vbox-uninstall-guest-additions
```

Comment: I moved a virtual machine to real hardware, and this worked for me.

Comment: Also worked for me on Oracle Linux 8: `sudo vbox-uninstall-guest-additions`

Comment: worked after migrating a virtualbox vm to vmware workstation on another machine

Comment: It would help to mention from where to run this command. It's confusing because to install guest additions, we are expected to start the VM and then use the menu options to install it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a try and search in the `/opt` directory. Virtualbox installs here the guest addition. You will find here the `uninstall.sh` script here.

E.g. on a debian system:

```
cd /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-6.1-35
sudo sh uninstall.sh
```

This will uninstall and update (initramfs) your machine; including the the `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-xxx` directory.

Answer (score -2):

Step 1: You can find all VBOX files here "C:\Program Files\ldplayerbox".
Step 2: Just download the Unlocker app from [here](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml#download)
Step 3: Run the Unlocker, and delete all "vbox" data.

Comment: after recompiling the kernel, I couldn't find C: in my Debian GNU/Linux VM... Gosh, my not-so-real computer has no not-so-hard disk now, why, Apple why you do such things to your DELL Latitude laptops?? ;P